# ERROR: "Failed to save. Insufficient permissions." When trying to save changes in VS Code

Tags: 18.04, permissions

I am using VS Code (1.30.02) and Ubuntu 18.04.  When I try to save any changes in VS Code, I get this error:

> Failed to save 'SomeFileName.js': Insufficient permissions. Select
>   'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.

I have the same issue if I try to create a new file:

> Permission denied writing to file
>   (file:///path/to/new/file/newfile.js)

I am making these changes or trying to create new files in my own directory.  I am new to Ubuntu, so I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  What is the issue?

Comment: I don't know or use VS Code but generally, you create and save files in your home directory (`/home/username`). If saving files in your home directory is not possible, something is wrong on another level. Saving files elsewhere should not be possible without some modification first and is not encouraged.

Comment: I am logged in and saving inside my home directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you somehow changed file ownerships in your home directory.

One way to correct this without endangering your system is

```
sudo chown -c -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

Explanation:

- `chown`: change the ownership of files/directories
- `-c`: report all changes
- `-R`: do this recursively (for all files/directories beneath the given one)
- `$USER:$USER`: change the owner and the group that owns the the entry to the user that issues the command (`sudo` preserves the values)
- `$HOME`: do this with your home directory

You can test those environment variables with the following commands

```
echo $USER
sudo echo $USER
echo $HOME
sudo echo $HOME
```

Comment: What if I dont want to change the folder permission because the owner is www-data and I need to serve the files on my apache? My user is in the group www-data and I can change files in the project folder via terminal but cannot change them via VS code. Any idea?

Comment: [SOLVED] I had to log out of linux and log back in in order to start working (prerequisite: the user has to be in the www-data group)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make changes and create new files with VsCode without changing the whole home directory ownerships.

You can just change the ownerships of your project folder.

```
sudo chown -c -R $USER:$USER (project folder)
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why he gets the same error whenever he tries to create new files in his own directory.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to the parent folder of the file in your terminal and enter the following code:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 filename
```

Comment: Please don't suggest 777 permissions blindly.

Comment: I had a similar issue recently, it was annoying to always click the "Retry as Sudo", whenever I want to save my work so I tried editing the permission of the folder containing the file to 777 and it worked for me. I thought maybe it could help him solve his also.