# Pasting images to a directory

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying to paste images on a folder created on htdocs folder but permission is denied. How do go about this without using terminal?
Regards

Comment: Generally when permission is denied it's because the folder you are trying to work with is "owned" by a different account. If your tags are correct and you're using XAMPP, then you'll want to determine what username and group that XAMPP is using for Apache, and add your account to the group. This way you will have a better chance of being able to save files.

Comment: Thanks. This helped https://askubuntu.com/a/1258163/1647629